# Getting values of radio buttons through php form class documentation

Tags: php

i have a form in which there is a field of gender male/female with radio buttons. I want that buttons should be checked according to the chosen value like i have chosen male then on edit page the male option should be checked but only with php form class documentation method or form-builder. I have made all the efforts any help would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
//if($row['gender'] == 'male'){

$frm->startTag('p') .
// add id to just one radio input (for html validity)
// label tag can't contain both (not valid html
$frm->addLabelFor('gender', 'Your gender: ') .
$frm->addInput('radio', 'gender', 'male', array('id'=>'gender','checked'=>true)  ) . ' male ' .
$frm->endTag() . PHP_EOL .
//}
//else{
$frm->startTag('p') .
$frm->addLabelFor('gender', 'Your gender: ') .
$frm->addInput('radio', 'gender', 'female', array('checked'=>true) ) . ' female ' .
$frm->endTag() . PHP_EOL .
//}
```

I had also used if else condition but didn't worked out.

Comment: So your "male" radio button isn't checked?

Comment: it is checked and it only select male value. I don't know where i am going wrong. please help and thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: What is your HTML output?

Comment: uid: 44 aq sq qs Male December Good.. Showing something like this. Is there any method in documentation for echoing  and get selected value as desired on edit page. Although updation works fine. Thanks...